# Can I delete trophy data of a PS4 game from my PSN account?

Tags: ps4, psn

Is it possible to delete trophy data from my PSN account for a game that I don't play and don't want in my trophy collection? (on PS4)

I got 1 trophy for the game (for literally just playing it for the first time) and decided I didn't like the game and now want it removed from my trophy list as it looks bad just sitting there with a 1% complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by what I can see, the only way to delete a trophy set is if it stands at 0% total. The only other alternative is to [hide trophies](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/privacy.html)

Select (Settings) > [PlayStation™Network/Account Management] > [Privacy Settings]. > Sharing Your Experience > Trophies

In there you can hide games, I believe!

Comment: yeah this is all I can seem to find too.. I guess maybe I'll just have to live with it. Thanks